# Splitting a folder in smaller ones with a certain size

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to divide a folder into folders with a maximum size of, let's say 8 GB.

starting folder:

```
 Folder 1
  2KB file
  2GB file
  7GB file
 Folder 2
  1GB file
  5.6GB file
 Folder 3
  8GB file
```

which i want to turn into:

```
  Folder A (~7.6GB)
   Folder 1
     2KB file
     2GB file
   Folder 2
     5.6GB file
 Folder B (8GB)
   Folder 1
     7GB file
   Folder 2
     1GB file
 Folder C (8GB)
   Folder 3
     8GB file
```

The goal is that you can combine the folders and get the structure of the original folder.

Is something like this even possible with powershell? I've seen some solutions with bash and dirsplit, but i'd really like to keep it in powershell, unless there is a simple and clean solution with some already existing software.

I forgot to add that the folders might not only include files, but sometimes folders too. Is there a solution that does this recursively to a certain extent?

It feels like i am missing something, considering i haven't worked a lot with powershell.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. This is one of these kinds of problems that seem trivial to solve, but is actually extremely hard to find an optimal solution to. Are you trying to fit the data into a finite set of folders (ie. split them across 3 folders) or a finite size (at most 8GB in each folder)?

Comment: An algorythm beginning with the largest files (for efficiency) would get same results, but a different order.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i want to split them across the lowest possible amount of folders.

Comment: You already have that (the subfolders are all contained in a single folder)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Ill reword this: I want to split them across the lowest possible amount of folders that have a size lower than 8GB

Comment: An ideal partitioning with each sub-folder as close to 8GB as possible is indeed hard to find (it seems similar to the partitioning or zero-sum problems in mathematics), but in this case no need to overthink if the naive summing approach in a sorted array of file sizes produces exactly `ceil(overall_size / 8GB)` number of folders.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think you're conflating packing the items with its associated decision problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of partitioning you describe is also know as a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

A fairly fast solution to this is known as the *first-fit algorithm* - imagine an infinite line of bins of a finite size, and simply pack each item into the next bin that has room for it. This can further be optimized by packing the *largest* items first (by sorting the items up front).

Below is a somewhat verbose implementation:

```
# Define the root path (the one that contains Folder1, Folder2 etc)
$RootPath = 'C:\data'

# Define the target path (where we'll create the new structure)
$TargetPath = 'C:\packed'

# Collect the file information, order by descending size (largest first)
$Files = Get-ChildItem $RootPath -File -Recurse |Sort-Object Length -Descending

# Define max bin size as the size of the largest file 
$Max = $Files[0].Length # puth 8GB here instead (fiels larger than 8GB will end up in a lone bin)

# Create a list of lists to group our files by
$Bins = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Generic.List[System.IO.FileInfo]]]::new()

:FileIteration
foreach($File in $Files){
    # Walk through existing bins to find one that has room
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $Bins.Count; $i++){
        if(($Bins[$i]|Measure Length -Sum).Sum -le ($Max - $File.Length)){
            # Add file to bin, continue the outer loop
            $Bins[$i].Add($File)
            continue FileIteration
        }
    }
    # No existing bins with capacity found, create a new one and add the file
    $NewBin = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.IO.FileInfo]]::new()
    $NewBin.Add($File)
    $Bins.Add($NewBin)
}

# Now go through the bins and move the files to the new directory
foreach($Bin in $Bins){
    # Create a new randomly named folder for the files in the bin
    $Directory = New-Item $TargetPath -Name $([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()) -ItemType Directory
    foreach($File in $Bin){
        # Recreate the parent folder inside the new folder if it doesn't already exist
        $ParentName = $File.Directory.Name
        $ParentPath = Join-Path $Directory.FullName -ChildPath $ParentName
        if(-not(Test-Path $ParentPath)){
            $ParentDirectory = New-Item $ParentPath -ItemType Directory
        }
        # Move file into new directory structure
        Move-Item $File.FullName -Destination $ParentPath
    }
}
```

*You can trivially skip the intermediate step of assigning each item to a list, and go straight to moving the files, but I feel that splitting the example into two makes it clearer/more readable what we're trying to do.*

Comment: Beat me to it! Very nice `:-)`

Comment: (just stumble on it years later) change "$Max = $Files[0].Length"  with "$Max = 8GB"