# Get random items from hashtable but the total of values has to be equal to a set number

Tags: powershell, random, max, hashtable

I'm trying to build a simple "task distributor" for the house tasks between me and my wife. Although the concept will be really useful at work too so I need to learn it properly.

My hashtable:

```
$Taches = @{
    "Balayeuse plancher" = 20
    "Moppe plancher" = 20
    "Douche" = 15
    "Litières" = 5
    "Poele" = 5
    "Comptoir" = 5
    "Lave-Vaisselle" = 10
    "Toilette" = 5
    "Lavabos" = 10
    "Couvertures lit" = 5
    "Poubelles" = 5
}
```

The total value for all the items is 105 (minutes).
So roughly 50mins each of we split it in two.

My goal:

I want to select random items from that hashtable and build two different hashtables - one for me and my wife, each having a total value of 50 (So it's fair). For example 20+20+10 or 5+5+5+15+20, etc. The hard part is that ALL tasks have to be accounted for between the two hashtables  and they can only be present ONCE  in each of them (no use in cleaning the same thing twice!).

What would be the best option?

For now I successfully achieved a random hashtable of a total value of 50 like this:

```
do {
    $Me = $null
    $sum = $null
    $Me = @{}
    $Me = $Taches.GetEnumerator() | Get-Random -Count 5
    $Me | ForEach-Object { $Sum += $_.value }
} until ($sum -eq 50)
```

Result example :

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Poubelles                      5
Balayeuse plancher             20
Douche                         15
Poele                          5
Toilette                       5
```

It works but boy does it feel like it's a roundabout and crooked way of doing it. I'm sure there is a better approach? Plus I'm lacking important things. ALL the tasks have to be accounted for and not be present twice. This is quite complicated although it looked simple at first!

Comment: What you've got here is known as [Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). See [Basic Analysis of Bin-Packing Heuristics](http://bastian.rieck.ru/research/Note_BP.pdf) which contains pseudo-code for well-known solving algorithms. Relevant question: [Splitting a folder in smaller ones with a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437769/splitting-a-folder-in-smaller-ones-with-a-certain-size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great answers guys, learned a lot. Here is what I ended up doing thanks to "Fischfreund" on Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/aovs8s/get_random_items_from_hashtable_but_the_total_of/eg3ytds).

His approach is amazingly simple yet I didn't think of it at all.

First hashtable : Get a random count of 5 until the sum is 50. Then create a second hashtable where the items are not in the first hashtable! I assign that first hahstable containing 5 items to my wife so I'm the one who always has an extra task (like suggested by Kory ;)). Phew i'm safe.

```
$Taches = @{

    "Balayeuse plancher" = 20
    "Moppe plancher"     = 20
    "Douche"             = 15
    "Litières"           = 5
    "Poele"              = 5
    "Comptoir"           = 5
    "Lave-Vaisselle"     = 10
    "Toilette"           = 5
    "Lavabos"            = 10
    "Couvertures lit"    = 5
    "Poubelles"          = 5

}

do {
$Selection1 = $Taches.GetEnumerator() | Get-Random -Count 5
} until (($Selection1.Value | measure -Sum ).Sum -eq 50)


$Selection2 = $Taches.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_ -notin $Selection1}


$Selection1 | select-object @{Name="Personne";expression={"Wife"} },Name,Value
""
$Selection2 | select-object @{Name="Personne";expression={"Me"} },Name,Value
```

Comment: While this approach seems simpler it does the same crooked brute force as your initial one. You'll have a problem finding the one taking always the overhead in a work envrionment.

Answer (score 4):

You can not maximise randomness and fairness at the same time so one has to give. I think you should not risk being unfair to your wife and so fairness must prevail!

## Fairness at the expense of randomness

This approach sorts the items in descending time order and then randomly assigns them items to each person unless that assignment would be unfair.

The fairness calculation here is that the maximum time difference should be at most the duration of the quickest task.

```
$DescendingOrder = $Taches.Keys | Sort-Object -Descending { $Taches[$_] }

$Measures = $Taches.Values | Measure-Object -Sum -Minimum
$UnfairLimit = ($Measures.Sum + $Measures.Minimum) / 2

$Person1 = @{}
$Person2 = @{}

$Total1 = 0
$Total2 = 0

foreach ($Item in $DescendingOrder) {

    $Time = $Taches[$Item]
    $Choice = Get-Random 2

    if (($Choice -eq 0) -and (($Total1 + $Time) -gt $UnfairLimit)) {
        $Choice = 1
    }

    if (($Choice -eq 1) -and (($Total2 + $Time) -gt $UnfairLimit)) {
        $Choice = 0
    }

    if ($Choice -eq 0) {
        $Person1[$Item] = $Time
        $Total1 += $Time
    } else {
        $Person2[$Item] = $Time
        $Total2 += $Time
    }
}
```

An example run:

```
PS> $Person1 | ConvertTo-Json

{
    "Comptoir":  5,
    "Lavabos":  10,
    "Litières":  5,
    "Couvertures lit":  5,
    "Douche":  15,
    "Lave-Vaisselle":  10
}
```

and the other person:

```
PS> $Person2 | ConvertTo-Json

{
    "Moppe plancher":  20,
    "Toilette":  5,
    "Balayeuse plancher":  20,
    "Poubelles":  5,
    "Poele":  5
}
```

## Randomness at the expense of fairness

This approach is to randomize the list, go through each item and then assign it to the person who has the least time allocated to them so far.

Earlier decisions might mean that later decisions end up being unfair.

```
$RandomOrder = $Taches.Keys | Sort-Object { Get-Random }

$Person1 = @{}
$Person2 = @{}

$Total1 = 0
$Total2 = 0

foreach ($Item in $RandomOrder) {

    $Time = $Taches[$Item]

    if ($Total1 -lt $Total2) {
        $Person1[$Item] = $Time
        $Total1 += $Time
    } else {
        $Person2[$Item] = $Time
        $Total2 += $Time
    }
}
```

An example run:

```
PS> $Person1 | ConvertTo-Json

{
    "Poele":  5,
    "Douche":  15,
    "Couvertures lit":  5,
    "Lave-Vaisselle":  10,
    "Balayeuse plancher":  20,
    "Toilette":  5
}
```

and the other person:

```
PS> $Person2 | ConvertTo-Json

{
    "Lavabos":  10,
    "Comptoir":  5,
    "Poubelles":  5,
    "Litières":  5,
    "Moppe plancher":  20
}
```

Comment: Great answer with two versions, I learned a lot with this thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably write the algorithm to always have you take the extra task in a rounding error (Happy Wife, Happy Life).

This is probably over-engineered, but I was intrigued by the question, and learned some French in the process.

```
$Taches = @{
"Balayeuse plancher" = 20
"Moppe plancher" = 20
"Douche" = 15
"Litières" = 5
"Poele" = 5
"Comptoir" = 5
"Lave-Vaisselle" = 10
"Toilette" = 5
"Lavabos" = 10
"Couvertures lit" = 5
"Poubelles" = 5
}

$target = 0
$epsilon = 5

# copy if you don't want to destroy original list (not needed probably)
# put all entries in first list.
# randomly move entry to p2 if count over target +/- epsilon 
# randomly move entry from p2 if count under target +/- epsilon 
# (unless you know you can always get exactly target and not loop forever trying)
$p1 = @{} # person 1
$p2 = @{} # person 2
$p1Total = 0 # optimizaton to not have to walk entire list and recalculate constantly
$p2Total = 0 # might as well track this too...
$Taches.Keys | % {
    $p1.Add($_, $Taches[$_])
    $p1Total += $Taches[$_]
    $target += $Taches[$_]
    }

$target = $target / 2

$done = $false
while (-not $done)
{
    if ($p1Total -gt ($target+$epsilon))
    {
        $item = $p1.Keys | Get-Random
        $value = $p1[$item]
        $p1.Remove($item)
        $p2.Add($item, $value)
        $p1Total -= $value
        $p2Total += $value
        continue
    }
    elseif ($p1Total -lt ($target-$epsilon))
    {
        $item = $p2.Keys | Get-Random
        $value = $p2[$item]
        $p2.Remove($item)
        $p1.Add($item, $value)
        $p1Total += $value
        $p2Total -= $value
        continue
    }

    $done = $true
}

"Final result"
"p1"
$p1Total
$p1

"`np2"
$p2Total
$p2
```

Comment: Haha love that idea to always take the extra task, I was thinking the same. Funny stuff. This is pretty hard for me to understand it all clearly but a great example for learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach:

```
$MinSum  = ($Taches.Values | Measure-Object -Minimum ).Minimum
$HalfSum = ($Taches.Values | Measure-Object -Sum ).Sum / 2
do {
    $sum = 0
    $All = $Taches.GetEnumerator() | 
        Get-Random -Count $Taches.Keys.Count
    $Me = $All | ForEach-Object { 
        if ( $Sum -lt $HalfSum - $MinSum ) { 
            $Sum += $_.value
            @{ $_.Key = $_.Value }
        }
    }
    Write-Host "$sum " -NoNewline   # debugging output
}  until ($sum -eq 50 )

$Em = $Taches.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    if ( $_ -notin $Me.Keys ) {
        @{ $_ = $Taches.$_ }
    }
}
# show "fairness" (task count vs. task cost) 
$Me.Values | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -Property Count, Sum
$Em.Values | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -Property Count, Sum
```

**Sample output**(s):

> ```
> PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\54610011.ps1
> 50 
> Count Sum
> ----- ---
>     4  50
>     7  55
>
> PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\54610011.ps1
> 65 65 50 
> Count Sum
> ----- ---
>     6  50
>     5  55
> ```